# How can I retrieve recent posts on LinkedIn using the LinkedIn API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve the data of recent posts on LinkedIn using the LinkedIn API. I have the "Advertising" and "Share on LinkedIn" permissions enabled, but I'm having trouble with the API endpoint.

When I use the "GET [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares"](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares%22) API as described in the documentation, I get the following error message:

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 0,
"message": "Resource shares does not exist",
"status": 404
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me figure out how to retrieve the data of recent posts on LinkedIn using the API? I'm using Postman and the OAuth 2.0 authentication flow with 3-legged OAuth.

Also tried "GET [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?ids=List({encoded ugcPostUrn},{encoded ugcPostUrn})](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?ids=List(%7Bencoded%20ugcPostUrn%7D,%7Bencoded%20ugcPostUrn%7D))" API for which i wasn't able to encoded ugcPostUrn.

For getting encoded ugcPostUrn i used "GET
[https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts?dscAdAccount={encode dscAdAccount}&q=dscAdAccount](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts?dscAdAccount=%7Bencode%20dscAdAccount%7D&q=dscAdAccount)" API {encode dscAdAccount} as "`urn:li:share:cdPbXlH6yd`" for which i got the response as:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request",
    "status": 400
}
```

If there is any other LinkedIn API that can provide me my and other person's posts please let me know.
Thanks in advance for any help!